# Questions about a dominated convergence theorem problem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, gamma-function

The problem is to find the derivative of Gamma function $\Gamma (y) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{e^{ - x}}{x^{y - 1}}dx} $ using dominated convergence theorem. Although the following content is lengthy, most of them are **background**. You **can scroll all the way down to my questions at the end** in bold. **My major problem is that I don't understand two inequities in the proof**.

The dominated convergence theorem (DCT).

> DCT states that for a sequence of function ${f_n}(x)$ defined on $E$ converging to $f$, if $|{f_n}(x)| \le g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is a Lebesgue integrable function on $E$, i.e. $\int_E {g(x)d\mu }  <  + \infty $, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_E f_n\,d\mu = \int_E \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n\,d\mu= \int_E f\,d\mu$

Step 1.

> $\begin{array}{l}
> \Gamma '(y) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{\Gamma (y + h) - \Gamma (y)}}{h}\\
>  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}[\int_0^\infty  {{e^{ - x}}{x^{y + h - 1}}} dx - \int_0^\infty  {{e^{ - x}}{x^{y - 1}}dx} ]\\
>  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \int_{[0,\infty )} {\frac{{{e^{ - x}}({x^{y + h - 1}} - {x^{y - 1}})}}{h}} dx
> \end{array}$

Step 2.

> By mean value theorem, $\exists \xi\in(y,y+h)$ such that $(\frac{{d{x^{y - 1}}}}{{dy}})(\xi ) = {x^{\xi  - 1}}\ln x = \frac{{{x^{y + h - 1}} - {x^{y - 1}}}}{h}$, thus $\Gamma '(y) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \int_{[0,\infty )} {{e^{ - x}}{x^{\xi  - 1}}\ln xdx} $.
>
> Note that $\xi\in(y,y+h)$, so $\xi$ is actually dependent on $h,y$,so we rewrite it as $\xi_{h,y}$. Thus $\Gamma '(y) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \int_{[0,\infty )} {{e^{ - x}}{x^{\xi_{h,y}  - 1}}\ln xdx} $.
>
> Denote ${f_h} = {e^{ - x}}{x^{{\xi _{h,y}} - 1}}\ln x$. Since $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} {\xi _{h,y}} = y$, we have $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} {f_h} = {e^{ - x}}{x^{y - 1}}\ln x$. Now if we can prove $|{f_h}(x)| \le g$ for some Lebesgue integrable function $g(x)$ on $[0,\infty)$, then
>
> $\begin{array}{l}
> \Gamma '(y) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \int_{[0,\infty )} {{e^{ - x}}{x^{{\xi _{h,y}} - 1}}\ln xdx} \\
>  = \int_{[0,\infty )} {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} {e^{ - x}}{x^{{\xi _{h,y}} - 1}}\ln xdx} \\
>  = \int_{[0,\infty )} {{e^{ - x}}{x^{y - 1}}\ln xdx} 
> \end{array}$
>
> and we are done.

**In step 2, I have one question.**
The index of $f_h(x)$ is continuous, so DCT holds when the index of function sequence is continuous? Can anyone provide a reference?

Step 3. is to prove $|{f_h}(x)| \le g(x)$ for some Lebesgue integrable function $g(x)$ on $[0,\infty)$, and

> Since $\xi_{h,y} \in (y,y+h)$ and $h\rightarrow 0$, we can choose a fixed value $0<\delta<1$ such that $\xi_{h,y} \in (y-\delta,y+\delta)$ holds when $|h|$ is sufficiently small. Then
>
> $\left| {{e^{ - x}}{x^{{\xi _{h,y}} - 1}}\ln x} \right| \le {e^{ - x}}\left| {\ln x} \right|{x^{y - \delta  - 1}} \le C{e^{ - x}}|x{|^{y - 2\delta  - 1}}$ when $0<x<1$
>
> $\left| {{e^{ - x}}{x^{{\xi _{h,y}} - 1}}\ln x} \right| \le ({e^{ - x}}\ln x){x^{y + \delta  - 1}} \le C{e^{ - \frac{x}{2}}}$ when $x\ge 1$

**I have a major problem with this step**. Why on earth the two inequities hold? I think $C$ represents a constant, and I under stand $\left| {{e^{ - x}}{x^{{\xi _{h,y}} - 1}}\ln x} \right| \le {e^{ - x}}\left| {\ln x} \right|{x^{y - \delta  - 1}}$ and $\left| {{e^{ - x}}{x^{{\xi _{h,y}} - 1}}\ln x} \right| \le ({e^{ - x}}\ln x){x^{y + \delta  - 1}}$, but **I DON'T UNDERSTAND** why inequity ${e^{ - x}}\left| {\ln x} \right|{x^{y - \delta  - 1}} \le C{e^{ - x}}|x{|^{y - 2\delta  - 1}}$ and $({e^{ - x}}\ln x){x^{y + \delta  - 1}} \le C{e^{ - \frac{x}{2}}}$ hold.

This solution is copied from my professor's blackboard handwriting, so possibly there might be mistake in step 3. If the inequities in step 3 is indeed incorrect, can you help give the right inequities? Thank you so much!

Comment: In Problems in real analysis by Aliprantis, Problem 24.13, he gave a very detail construction of g(x) in detail and should be helpful.  Theorem 57 and 58  in https://037598a680dc5e00a4d1feafd699642badaa7a8c.googledrive.com/host/0B4HffVs7117IbmZ2OTdKSVBZLVk/MA3110/Chapter%2014%20Improper%20Integrals.pdf  gave the result for differentiation under the integral sign with a slightly different proof than Aliprantis Principle of Real analysis Theorem 24.4 , Theorem 24.5.  The use of the Lebesgue Dominated convergence Theorem is in the proof of Theorem  57 or Theorem 24.4 in Aliprantis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well it's a general result that 
$$
\lim \limits_{y \to x} f(y) = l
$$
if and only if 
$$
\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f(y_n) = l,
$$
for all sequences $y_n$ such that $y_n \to x, y_n \neq x. $
(This is easy to prove for further discussion see my book "Proof patterns")

So the DCT goes over.

For your second point. He is using basic properties of logs:
$$
x^{\delta} \log x
$$
is bounded as $x \to 0,$ for any $\delta >0.$

and
$$
e^{-x/2} \log x
$$
is bounded as $x \to \infty.$ this is obvious from the fact that $\log$ grows more slowly than any polynomial, and $e^{x}$ grows faster than any polynomial.

Comment: In fact the maximum of $e^{-x/2}\log x$ occurs at $x=2/W(2)$, where $W(2) \approx. 0.85260436065397$ is the Lambert W Function evaluated at $2$.  The value $e^{-W(2)^{-1}}\left(\log 2-\log W(2)\right)\approx. 0.263860771$.  Good answer!  +1